# String equal issue when comparing with socket input stream

Tags: java, string

### Edited:

Sorry for not making things clear, and I found the issue have nothing to do with enum:

For my case, the enum looks like this, I used the contains method to check if a string value belongs to:

```
    public static enum RequestMethod {
    HEAD, GET, POST;

    public static boolean contains(String test) {

        for (RequestMethod m : RequestMethod.values()) {
            System.out.println("Testing: method |"+m.name()+"|, input |"+test+"|");
            if (m.name().equals(test.trim())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the server side testing code is:

```
Socket clientSock;
......

InputStream clientInput = clientSock.getInputStream()
BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            clientInput));

String buffer = inStream.readLine();
String[] reqLine  = buffer.split(" ");

System.out.println("test GET---");
System.out.println(Request.RequestMethod.contains("GET"));
System.out.println("test GET---");

System.out.println("test reqLine[0]---");
System.out.println(Request.RequestMethod.contains(reqLine[0]));
System.out.println("test reqLine[0]---");

System.out.println("reqLine[0] equals GET? " + reqLine[0].equals("GET"));
```

When client sent "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0" through socket to server, the output is:

```
Client send: GET /index.html HTTP/1.0
test GET---
Testing: method |HEAD|, input |GET|
Testing: method |GET|, input |GET|
true
test GET---

test reqLine[0]---
Testing: method |HEAD|, input |GET|
Testing: method |GET|, input |GET|
Testing: method |POST|, input |GET|
false
test reqLine[0]---

reqLine[0] equals GET? false
```

The reqLine[0] printed as "GET", however they're considered not equal, which causes issues.

So I went to check how did the client (which is provided to me) put the data into socket, I found:

```
Socket sock;
......
DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
outStream.writeChars(buffer); // this line causes issue
outStream.writeChar('\n');
outStream.flush();
```

When I change the **writeChars** to **writeBytes**, the string equals on server side works as expected.

```
test GET---
Testing: method |HEAD|, input |GET|
Testing: method |GET|, input |GET|
true
test GET---

test reqLine[0]---
Testing: method |HEAD|, input |GET|
Testing: method |GET|, input |GET|
true
test reqLine[0]---

GET equals reqLine[0]? true
```

I shouldn't have post this question when having a fuzzy brain.

Then I guess my question should be changed to: Why do the strings sent by **writeChars** and **writeBytes** has same printing result but are not equal?

Is it because writeChar(writeChars) write each char as 2 bytes?

> writeChar
>
> public final void writeChar(int v)
>                        throws IOException
>
> Writes a char to the underlying output stream as a 2-byte value, high byte first. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by 2.

Comment: The obvious explanation is that test isn't any of the Choice enum names. What are the names, and what is the value of test? What isprinted when you write their length and you dump the integer value of each of their characters?

Comment: Please give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you can post a [mcve] to reproduce the issue, I'm sure it'll be simple to explain. Without that, we'd just be guessing. At the moment we don't even know exactly how you're reading the `test` string...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your code above. I defined my own ENUM Choice.

```
public enum Choice {
GOOD, BAD, UGLY}
```

And then tested your above method with

```
contains("BAD") -> This returned true.
contains("BAD1") -> This returned false
```

Comment: I always comment before giving -1, it doesn't answer the question